# Creating a UICellAccessory.customView instance and using it in multiple listCell accessories causes hang

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessory, uicollectionviewlistcell

I wanted to make a UI like this.

[image]

The component of the chevron down image on the right side of the cell is the `UICellAccessory` that I customized. From now on, I will call this `moreAccessory`.

To make this UI, I configured the `dataSource` with `redCellRegistration` and `blueCellRegistration` as follows.

```swift
let redCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .red
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"))
    let configuration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(customView: image,
                                                                placement: .trailing(),
                                                                tintColor: .systemGray)
    let moreAccessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: configuration)
    cell.accessories = [moreAccessory]
}

let blueCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .blue
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"))
    let configuration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(customView: image,
                                                                placement: .trailing(),
                                                                tintColor: .systemGray)
    let moreAccessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: configuration)
    cell.accessories = [moreAccessory]
}

dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
    (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
    
    if indexPath.row.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: redCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
    } else {
        return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: blueCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
    }
}
```

And I recognized that there was a duplicate code for creating `moreAccessory` instance in `redCellRegistration` and `blueCellRegistration`, so decided to make this accessory a single variable and use it in common.

```swift
let moreAccessory: UICellAccessory = {
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"))
    let configuration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(customView: image,
                                                                placement: .trailing(),
                                                                tintColor: .systemGray)
    let accessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: configuration)
    return accessory
}()


let redCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .red
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    cell.accessories = [moreAccessory]
}

let blueCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .blue
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    cell.accessories = [moreAccessory]
}
```

But the code above caused hang.

When looking at the Instruments tool, `UICellAccessoryManager_updateAccessories:prevailingAccessories:withLayout:edge:` function occupied too much weight.

[image]

The usage of cpu was 100%, and the memory usage also continued to go up.

However, if I create and use an accessory through a function that returns `moreAccessory`, there was no error in this situation.

```swift
func moreAccessory() -> UICellAccessory {
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"))
    let configuration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(customView: image,
                                                                placement: .trailing(),
                                                                tintColor: .systemGray)
    let accessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: configuration)
    return accessory
}

let redCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .red
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    cell.accessories = [moreAccessory()]
}

let blueCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .blue
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    cell.accessories = [moreAccessory()]
}
```

I thought, "Well, was it a problem to use the same instance?". And assigned `moreAccessory` to the variables in `redCellRegistration` and `blueCellRegistration` separately. (Because the `UICellAccessory` is struct, if I assign it to a variable, the instance will be copied.)

```swift
let moreAccessory: UICellAccessory = {
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down"))
    let configuration = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(customView: image,
                                                                placement: .trailing(),
                                                                tintColor: .systemGray)
    let accessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: configuration)
    return accessory
}()

let redCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .red
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    let redCellAccessory = moreAccessory
    cell.accessories = [redCellAccessory]
}

let blueCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "\(item)"
    content.textProperties.color = .blue
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    let blueCellAccessory = moreAccessory
    cell.accessories = [blueCellAccessory]
}
```

However, there was an error at this time, too.

And If I make `moreAccessory` as a predefined accessory such as `disclosureIndicator`, not `customView`, there was no error.

```swift
let moreAccessory: UICellAccessory = {
    let accessory = UICellAccessory.disclosureIndicator()
    return accessory
}()
```

[image]
Is there anything to get a clue about this error situation?

Comment: I can't speak to why there is a problem sharing the same instance but do note that in the documentation for [`UICellAccessory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicellaccessory), all of the system accessories are defined as functions, not as constants. So it seems the pattern is that every accessory must be a unique instance and not shared.

Comment: Like I described above, if is the matter of not using a “unique instance”, doesn't the error has not to occurred when I assign `moreAccessory` to each new constant? (as `UICellAccessory` is struct instance, it is copied and no more unique I thought.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICellAccessory` is a struct, but the `UIView` subclass it contains when creating a custom accessory is a class. When the struct is copied, the same view instance will be used; a new view will *not* be created. You cannot share the same single custom view (a `UIImageView` in your example) between cells.

You have already found the correct solution: you need to make a new instance of `UICellAccessory` for every separate row if you are using a custom view. Your original code worked, but to avoid the duplication you can have a factory method to create a new cell accessory. That was your other solution that worked because it was creating a new instance each time it was called.